# How to keep a class instance alive?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've encapsulated a feature in a class to be used by a window (let's call this class Foo). Foo is instanciated in the window constructor but after that, it needs nothing other than existing until the end of the window. The problem is that Visual Studio tells me that the private member assigned to Foo instance can be removed because it is never read (I don't use Foo instance anywhere else in the window except in the constructor).

> IDE0052    Private member '_foo' can be removed as the value assigned to it is never read

I guess that make Foo a candidate to garbage collection but maybe there is something that will keep Foo alive that I'm not aware of. The problem could be solved by deriving from Window and implementing the feature and using that as a base Window class but Foo is not the only one feature like that and C# doesn't handle multiple inheritance. Any comment or advice is welcome.

PS: This is a WPF application in a MVVM pattern.

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{
    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _foo = new Foo(this);
    }

    // Could that be a solution (but it's annoying) ?
    //
    //~MainView()
    //{
    //    GC.KeepAlive(_foo);
    //}
}
```

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    public Foo(Window window)
    {
        window.SourceInitialized += OnSourceInitialized;
        window.Closed += OnClosed;
    }

    private void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSomething();
    }

    private void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not let it go out of scope so GC does not free it

Comment: Wait, that is a warning, not an error right? Your program compiles fine and I bet it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to store your `Foo` instance in any variable. It will be kept alive by the window because it attaches itself to events on the window here:

```
window.SourceInitialized += OnSourceInitialized;
window.Closed += OnClosed;
```

Because of those event registrations, `window` will have a reference to `this` (instance of `Foo`) and therefore the garbage collector will not destroy it. `Foo` will stay alive until the window instance is destroyed, at which point `Foo` will no longer have a reference and be cleaned up.

(If `Foo` decided at some point to unregister those event listeners, then it would also get destroyed in that case.)

P.S. The warning about the variable never being read is to indicate that you have a variable that you don't need to have. It is not in any way indicating what the garbage collector will do.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is an object that holds a reference to instance of foo, foo won't be garbage collected. What visual studio trying to say is you can remove this piece of code because you are not using it anywhere, it is purely related to code quality not garbage collection.